# block execution flow until script execution is completed

Tags: c++, system

I'm calling a script through C++ code bellow

```
 system("chmod 777 script");
 system("./script");  
 .
 .
 .
 test = new asebt::TestFactory();
```

and I need to prevent that the object TestFactory() being instantiated until the script is fully executed. How do I identify if this script has already been executed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the (integer) return value of the `system()` function is the status code of the called command. Execution halts until the `system()` function returns, so the script will always have finished running before later lines are executed.

Answer (score 0):

When your `system` call returns, your script has fully executed (unless it backgrounds another subprocess without waiting for it). `system` is totally synchronous in that way.